C# Oracle this operation requires the objects to use the same connection
I am trying to use the Oracle C# API (OracleDependency) so that my application gets notified by Oracle when a row is added, modified, or deleted. For this, I first register the tables on which I want to receive notifications. Everything works fine as long as I use the same Oracle connection. However, I would like my application to listen on multiple Oracle databases. Whether I use a single OracleDependency for all or one for each connection, I get the same error: 'this operation requires the objects to use the same connection.
This error appears on the line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Thanks
private void registerDependency(string tableName, OracleConnection cnx)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, cnx);
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating command for {tableName}, cmd instance: {cmd.GetHashCode()}");

        try
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            return;
        }
        var dep = createOracleDependency();
        dep.AddCommandDependency(cmd);

        cmd.AddRowid = true;
        cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Erreur : {e.Message}");
        }
    }


Do you really need to execute the query first? Try removing that entire first try/catch block.
